# How to calculate per document probabilities under respective topics with BERTopics?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I am trying to use `BERTopic` to analyze the topic distribution of documents, after `BERTopic` is performed, I would like to calculate the probabilities under respective topics per document, how should I did it?

```py
# define model
model = BERTopic(verbose=True,
                 vectorizer_model=vectorizer_model,
                 embedding_model='paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2',
                 min_topic_size= 50,
                 nr_topics=10)

#  train model
headline_topics, _ = model.fit_transform(df1.review_processed3)

# examine one of the topic
a_topic = freq.iloc[0]["Topic"] # Select the 1st topic
model.get_topic(a_topic) # Show the words and their c-TF-IDF scores
```

Below is the words and their c-TF-IDF scores for one of the Topics
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOwsD.png)

How should I change the result into Topic Distribution as below in order to calculate the topic distribution score and also identify the main topic?
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MX0j.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to compute probabilities, you have to add to your model definition `calculate_probabilities=True` (this could slow down the extraction of topics if you have many documents, > 100000).

```
# define model
model = BERTopic(verbose=True,
                 vectorizer_model=vectorizer_model,
                 embedding_model='paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2',
                 min_topic_size= 50,
                 nr_topics=10,
                 calculate_probabilities=True)
```

Then, calling `fit_transform`, you should save the probabilities:

```
headline_topics, probs = model.fit_transform(df1.review_processed3)
```

Now, you can create a pandas dataframe which shows probabilities under respective topics per document.

```
import pandas as pd
probs_df=pd.DataFrame(probs)
probs_df['main percentage'] = pd.DataFrame({'max': probs_df.max(axis=1)})
```